# Identity Server: Redirect after login and logout in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer in an Angular project based on .NET Core and I use the Identity Server razor login page by modifying it. Except from this login page, I use Angular pages and redirect the related pages using lazy-loading feature in Angular.

However, I need some different scenarios for after login and logout as explained below:

**1.** After user login, I want to redirect a specific page. How can I set this page? In the IdentityServer action methods, or in the login button's onClick action? I can also use href via a hperlink?

**2.** Should I use an `ActionLink`, etc as the login page is razor by redirecting the page to a Controller and then open an Angular page? Or is it better to use a href or routerlink property for the login button and call the related Angular route easily?

**3.** For the logout, I want to redirect an Angular page. Should I set it in the logout or logout callback properties of IdentityServer configuration?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** Here is the constant file that can be used for redirect or callback setup:

```
export const LogoutActions = {
  LogoutCallback: 'logout-callback',
  Logout: 'logout',
  LoggedOut: 'logged-out'
};

export const LoginActions = {
  Login: 'login',
  LoginCallback: 'login-callback',
  LoginFailed: 'login-failed',
  Profile: 'profile',
  Register: 'register'
};

let applicationPaths: ApplicationPathsType = {
  DefaultLoginRedirectPath: '/',
  ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl: `/_configuration/${ApplicationName}`,
  Login: `authentication/${LoginActions.Login}`,
  LoginFailed: `authentication/${LoginActions.LoginFailed}`,
  LoginCallback: `authentication/${LoginActions.LoginCallback}`,
  Register: `authentication/${LoginActions.Register}`,
  Profile: `authentication/${LoginActions.Profile}`,
  LogOut: `authentication/${LogoutActions.Logout}`,
  LoggedOut: `authentication/${LogoutActions.LoggedOut}`,
  LogOutCallback: `authentication/${LogoutActions.LogoutCallback}`,
  LoginPathComponents: [],
  LoginFailedPathComponents: [],
  LoginCallbackPathComponents: [],
  RegisterPathComponents: [],
  ProfilePathComponents: [],
  LogOutPathComponents: [],
  LoggedOutPathComponents: [],
  LogOutCallbackPathComponents: [],
  IdentityRegisterPath: '/Identity/Account/Register',
  IdentityManagePath: '/Identity/Account/Manage'
};

applicationPaths = {
  ...applicationPaths,
  LoginPathComponents: applicationPaths.Login.split('/'),
  LoginFailedPathComponents: applicationPaths.LoginFailed.split('/'),
  RegisterPathComponents: applicationPaths.Register.split('/'),
  ProfilePathComponents: applicationPaths.Profile.split('/'),
  LogOutPathComponents: applicationPaths.LogOut.split('/'),
  LoggedOutPathComponents: applicationPaths.LoggedOut.split('/'),
  LogOutCallbackPathComponents: applicationPaths.LogOutCallback.split('/')
};
```

Comment: What is your setup like?  Are you connecting to to IdentityServer via oidc-connect.js, using a Backend for Frontend setup, etc?  Can you post how your Client is configured on Identity server?

Comment: Yes, via via oidc-connect.js using frontend setup. I also add the config api-authorization constants in the question. thanks a lot.

Comment: What redirect URIs do you have configured in Identity server for the client and when you are configuring the oidc-client usermanager what is set for redirect_uri?  Once you log in via Identity Server it will redirect to what is sent over from the client.

Comment: **1.** I just need to be clarified on that; Let's say I have two components: componentA and componentB. After user logins via IdentityServer, I want to redirect to componentA and after logout I want to redirect to componentB. So, how can I  set these pages?

Comment: **2.** And in the login button of IdentityServer login page (I modified it), should I use `@Html.ActionLink()` or simly use href property and set an Angular route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to want to do is set up your IdentityServer client configuration to to point to those different components via the `RedirectUris` and `PostLogoutRedirectUris`.  Then within the Angular application, when you are configuring the `UserManager` instance set the `redirect_uri` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` where you want the Identity Server to redirect to after the Login/Logout methods complete.  These configurations need to match up between the client and server otherwise IdentityServer will reject the request.  A sample app from Brock Allen for Angular sheds some light on this, [Angular oidc-client.js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/dev/samples/Angular/App).

Once the configuration is completed the redirects should be automatic and you shouldn't need to modify the redirects in IdentityServer.  That only covers the Login/Logout flows.  I see you have register and failed login definitions within the Angular app.  What you could do is modify the View Controllers to redirect the user via a `return Redirect("some\url\to\angular\component");` to send the user to that component.

Answer (score 0):

**Identity Server: Redirect after login in Angular**

api-authorization.constants.ts

```
let applicationPaths: ApplicationPathsType = {
  DefaultLoginRedirectPath: 'yourPath',
}
```