# Identity Server 4 does not redirect to Angular clients PostLogoutRedirectUri after logout

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I'm new to Angular and Identity Server 4 and was hoping that someone could help me with this issue.

I have an angular application that uses Identity Server 4 to login.  This works fine when logging in, however, after logging out I'm not redirected back to the client application.  Instead I get the standard Identity Server 4 "you are now logged out" page.

It appears that the following line of code is responsible for retrieving the properties for the LoggedOutViewModel, which it does except for the PostLogoutRedirectUri property that returns null.

```
var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
```

There is no error shown in the browser console and the identiy server log shows the following:

> [12:52:16 Information]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
> AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed out.
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
> SignOutCalled set; processing post-signout session cleanup.
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client car_rental_app succeeded.
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.LogoutNotificationService No
> client back-channel logout URLs
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Request path
> /connect/endsession/callback matched to endpoint type Endsession
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter Endpoint
> enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler:
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
>
> [12:52:16 Information]
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware Invoking
> IdentityServer endpoint:
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint for
> /connect/endsession/callback
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
> Processing signout callback request
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore client
> configuration validation for client car_rental_app succeeded.
>
> [12:52:16 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.LogoutNotificationService No
> client front-channel logout URLs
>
> [12:52:16 Information]
> IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint Successful
> signout callback.

Below is the code from the identity application:

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {     
                new Client {
                    ClientId = "car_rental_app",
                    ClientName = "Car_Rental_App",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile" },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:8100",
                        "http://localhost:8100/signin-callback",
                        "http://localhost:8100/auth-callback"},
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8100/signout-callback" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:8100" },
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600,
                    RefreshTokenUsage=TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true
                }               
            };

    }
}




namespace IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI
{
    public class AccountOptions
    {
        public static bool AllowLocalLogin = true;
        public static bool AllowRememberLogin = true;
        public static TimeSpan RememberMeLoginDuration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);

        public static bool ShowLogoutPrompt = false;
        public static bool AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;

        public static string InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password";

        public static bool WindowsAuthenticationEnabled = false;
      
    }
}


@model LoggedOutViewModel

@{ 
    // set this so the layout rendering sees an anonymous user
    ViewData["signed-out"] = true;
}

<div class="logged-out-page">
    <h1>
        Logout
        <small>You are now logged out</small>
    </h1>

    @if (Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri != null)
    {
        <div>
            Click <a class="PostLogoutRedirectUri" href="@Model.PostLogoutRedirectUri">here</a> to return to the
            <span>@Model.ClientName</span> application.
        </div>
    }

    @if (Model.SignOutIframeUrl != null)
    {
        <iframe width="0" height="0" class="signout" src="@Model.SignOutIframeUrl"></iframe>
    }
</div>

@section scripts
{
    @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut)
    {
        <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>
    }
}


namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();


            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);
            

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", corsBuilder =>
                {
                    corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => origin == "http://localhost:8100")
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
            
            services.AddMvc();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // uncomment if you want to add MVC
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
    }
}



namespace IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This sample controller implements a typical login/logout/provision workflow for local and external accounts.
    /// The login service encapsulates the interactions with the user data store. This data store is in-memory only and cannot be used for production!
    /// The interaction service provides a way for the UI to communicate with identityserver for validation and context retrieval
    /// </summary>
    [SecurityHeaders]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TestUserStore _users;
        private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
        private readonly IClientStore _clientStore;
        private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
        private readonly IEventService _events;

        public AccountController(
            IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
            IClientStore clientStore,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IEventService events,
            TestUserStore users = null)
        {
            // if the TestUserStore is not in DI, then we'll just use the global users collection
            // this is where you would plug in your own custom identity management library (e.g. ASP.NET Identity)
            _users = users ?? new TestUserStore(TestUsers.Users);

            _interaction = interaction;
            _clientStore = clientStore;
            _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
            _events = events;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Entry point into the login workflow
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

            if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
            {
                // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
                return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { scheme = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
            }

            return View(vm);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle postback from username/password login
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
        {
            // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);

            // the user clicked the "cancel" button
            if (button != "login")
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
                    // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
                    // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
                    await _interaction.DenyAuthorizationAsync(context, AuthorizationError.AccessDenied);

                    // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                    if (context.IsNativeClient())
                    {
                        // The client is native, so this change in how to
                        // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                        return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // validate username/password against in-memory store
                if (_users.ValidateCredentials(model.Username, model.Password))
                {
                    var user = _users.FindByUsername(model.Username);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.SubjectId, user.Username, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));

                    // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                    // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                    {
                        props = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                        };
                    };

                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.Username
                    };

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);

                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (context.IsNativeClient())
                        {
                            // The client is native, so this change in how to
                            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                        }

                        // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    // request for a local page
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                    }
                }

                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials", clientId:context?.Client.ClientId));
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
            }

            // something went wrong, show form with error
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
            return View(vm);
        }

        
        /// <summary>
        /// Show logout page
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string logoutId)
        {
            // build a model so the logout page knows what to display
            var vm = await BuildLogoutViewModelAsync(logoutId);

            if (vm.ShowLogoutPrompt == false)
            {
                // if the request for logout was properly authenticated from IdentityServer, then
                // we don't need to show the prompt and can just log the user out directly.
                return await Logout(vm);
            }

            return View(vm);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle logout page postback
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
        {
            // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
            var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

            if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                // delete local authentication cookie
                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

                // raise the logout event
                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
            }

            // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
            if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
            {
                // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
                // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
                // complete our single sign-out processing.
                string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

                // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
                return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
            }

            if (vm.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri))
            {
                return Redirect(vm.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("LoggedOut", vm);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }


        /*****************************************/
        /* helper APIs for the AccountController */
        /*****************************************/
        private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(string returnUrl)
        {
            var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
            if (context?.IdP != null && await _schemeProvider.GetSchemeAsync(context.IdP) != null)
            {
                var local = context.IdP == IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider;

                // this is meant to short circuit the UI and only trigger the one external IdP
                var vm = new LoginViewModel
                {
                    EnableLocalLogin = local,
                    ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                    Username = context?.LoginHint,
                };

                if (!local)
                {
                    vm.ExternalProviders = new[] { new ExternalProvider { AuthenticationScheme = context.IdP } };
                }

                return vm;
            }

            var schemes = await _schemeProvider.GetAllSchemesAsync();

            var providers = schemes
                .Where(x => x.DisplayName != null)
                .Select(x => new ExternalProvider
                {
                    DisplayName = x.DisplayName ?? x.Name,
                    AuthenticationScheme = x.Name
                }).ToList();

            var allowLocal = true;
            if (context?.Client.ClientId != null)
            {
                var client = await _clientStore.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(context.Client.ClientId);
                if (client != null)
                {
                    allowLocal = client.EnableLocalLogin;

                    if (client.IdentityProviderRestrictions != null && client.IdentityProviderRestrictions.Any())
                    {
                        providers = providers.Where(provider => client.IdentityProviderRestrictions.Contains(provider.AuthenticationScheme)).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }

            return new LoginViewModel
            {
                AllowRememberLogin = AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin,
                EnableLocalLogin = allowLocal && AccountOptions.AllowLocalLogin,
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                Username = context?.LoginHint,
                ExternalProviders = providers.ToArray()
            };
        }

        private async Task<LoginViewModel> BuildLoginViewModelAsync(LoginInputModel model)
        {
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model.ReturnUrl);
            vm.Username = model.Username;
            vm.RememberLogin = model.RememberLogin;
            return vm;
        }

        private async Task<LogoutViewModel> BuildLogoutViewModelAsync(string logoutId)
        {
            var vm = new LogoutViewModel { LogoutId = logoutId, ShowLogoutPrompt = AccountOptions.ShowLogoutPrompt };

            if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated != true)
            {
                // if the user is not authenticated, then just show logged out page
                vm.ShowLogoutPrompt = false;
                return vm;
            }

            var context = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);
            if (context?.ShowSignoutPrompt == false)
            {
                // it's safe to automatically sign-out
                vm.ShowLogoutPrompt = false;
                return vm;
            }

            // show the logout prompt. this prevents attacks where the user
            // is automatically signed out by another malicious web page.
            return vm;
        }

        private async Task<LoggedOutViewModel> BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(string logoutId)
        {
            // get context information (client name, post logout redirect URI and iframe for federated signout)
            var logout = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);

            var vm = new LoggedOutViewModel
            {
                AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = AccountOptions.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = logout?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                ClientName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(logout?.ClientName) ? logout?.ClientId : logout?.ClientName,
                SignOutIframeUrl = logout?.SignOutIFrameUrl,
                LogoutId = logoutId
            };

            if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                var idp = User.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider)?.Value;
                if (idp != null && idp != IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider)
                {
                    var providerSupportsSignout = await HttpContext.GetSchemeSupportsSignOutAsync(idp);
                    if (providerSupportsSignout)
                    {
                        if (vm.LogoutId == null)
                        {
                            // if there's no current logout context, we need to create one
                            // this captures necessary info from the current logged in user
                            // before we signout and redirect away to the external IdP for signout
                            vm.LogoutId = await _interaction.CreateLogoutContextAsync();
                        }

                        vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme = idp;
                    }
                }
            }

            return vm;
        }
    }
}
```

Below are the relevant Angular files:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SigninRedirectCallbackComponent } from './home/signin-redirect-callback.component';
import { SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent } from './home/signout-redirect-callback.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SigninRedirectCallbackComponent,
    SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

auth-service.component.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule } from './core.module';
import { UserManager, User } from 'oidc-client';
import { Constants } from '../constants';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})

export class AuthService {

    private _userManager: UserManager;
    private _user: User;
    private _loginChangedSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

    loginChanged = this._loginChangedSubject.asObservable();
    
    constructor() {
        const stsSettings = {
            authority: Constants.stsAuthority,
            client_id: Constants.clientId,
            redirect_uri: Constants.clientRoot + '/signin-callback',
            scope: 'openid profile',
            response_type: 'code',
            post_logout_redirect_url: Constants.clientRoot + '/signout-callback'
        }

        this._userManager = new UserManager(stsSettings);
    }

    login() {
        return this._userManager.signinRedirect();
    }

    isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
        return this._userManager.getUser().then(user => {
            const userCurrent = !!user && !user.expired;
            if (this._user !== user) {
                this._loginChangedSubject.next(userCurrent);
            }
            this._user = user;
            return userCurrent;
        });
    }

    completeLogin() {
        return this._userManager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
          this._user = user;
          this._loginChangedSubject.next(!!user && !user.expired);
          return user;
        });
      }
    
    logout() {
     
      this._userManager.signoutRedirect({id_token_hint: this._user.id_token});
    }
  
    completeLogout() {
      this._user = null;
      return this._userManager.signoutRedirectCallback();
    }
}
```

signout-redirect-callback.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth-service.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signout-callback',
  template: `<div></div>`
})

export class SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService,
              private _router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._authService.completeLogout().then(_ => {
      this._router.navigate(['/'], { replaceUrl: true });
    })
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninRedirectCallbackComponent } from './home/signin-redirect-callback.component';
import { SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent } from './home/signout-redirect-callback.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { 
    path: 'signin-callback', component: SigninRedirectCallbackComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: 'signout-callback', component: SignoutRedirectCallbackComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874615/4838195